# How to change popup color in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

In Kivy, Popup appears in grey color, what should be changed to make it red color

My popup code:

```
class MyPopup(Popup):
    def show_popup(self):
        content = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        content.add_widget(Label(text="Game Over", font_size=20))
        mybutton_cancel = Button(text="Cancel", size_hint_y=None)
        content.add_widget(mybutton_cancel)

        mypopup = Popup(content = content,              
            title = "oops", 
            auto_dismiss = False,         
            size_hint = (.5, .5))
        mybutton_cancel.bind(on_release=mypopup.dismiss)
        mypopup.open()
```

I hope , it is clear that i am talking about popup color and not color of background screen behind popup or popup text color. I am talking about the color of popup rectangle. Please advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Popup` as a child of `ModalView` has a `StringProperty` called `background`, which points to an image from at atlas. The default one is `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/modalview-background`. Here I changed it to one of the default button images:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return  Button(text="show", on_press=self.anim_btn)

    def anim_btn(self, *args):
        popup = Popup(title='Test popup', 
            content=Label(text='Hello world'), 
            size_hint=(None, None), 
            size=(400, 400),
            background = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed'
        ).open()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

This default theme resides here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme-0.png In order to customize your popup (and also, for example, buttons) you can create your own atlas (http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it' so late, but since you needed a popup with a red color:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return  Button(text="show", on_press=self.anim_btn)

    def anim_btn(self, *args):
        popup = Popup(title='Test popup', 
            content=Label(text='Hello world'), 
            size_hint=(None, None), 
            size=(400, 400),
            separator_color=[.9,.4,.2,1],
            background_color=[4,.4,.2,1]
        ).open()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```