# How to correctly specify the relative path to kivy atlas and the image in it?

Tags: python-3.x, popup, kivy

I am trying to change the Popup background as per the answer in this question:
[How to change popup color in kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141937/how-to-change-popup-color-in-kivy)

In the directory of my project there is a folder **Images** and a file **main.py**. In the Images folder there are 2 64 by 64 images:popup_background.png, popup_background_green.png

First, I create an atlas using the command:

```
python -m kivy.atlas myatlas 256x256 popup_background.png popup_background_green.png
```

After execution, the necessary files appear in the folder

Here is my code:

```
cnt = Button(text='Close', size_hint=(0.3, 0.2))
popup = Popup(title='AlertTitle',
              content=cnt,
              size_hint=(.5, .5),
              background='atlas://Images/myatlas/popup_background')
```

When the **Popup** is launched, it is **completely black color** (the title, button and separator are clearly visible) instead of the expected image in the atlas.

I tried a lot of experiments to get the expected image, but nothing worked. Instead, I don't understand how, but this path works and changes color:'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed'
I assume that it finds the image in the files of the library itself, but how?

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Look at the myatlas.atlas file (it should be just json text). There should be a dictionary of dictionaries. The top level dictionary should have a key that is the name of a png file (something like `myatlas-0.png`) that contains both your `popup_background.png` and `popup_background_green.png`. The keys of the inner dictionary should be `popup_background` and `popup_background_green`. Is that what you see? Is the `myatlas-0.png` in the same folder?

Comment: Content of myatlas.atlas file: 
{"myatlas-0.png": {"popup_background": [2, 190, 64, 64], "popup_background_green": [68, 190, 64, 64]}}

All images mentioned in the file are in the Images folder as well as the atlas.
Pay attention to the second option that I indicated, it somehow works, and I need to know why.

Comment: I just created a new project and did the same, everything worked. The relative path works great, but something prevents it from working specifically in the previous project, I'll write what the problem was when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my code in detail and realized that the problem is in creating and displaying popup, as well as changing its properties in a **separate thread**, I missed it. Therefore, the background did not change.

If you also have a need to change properties in a different thread, use the `@mainthread` decorator on the desired function.

Import:

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread
```